# How to Connect to Peers in OpenDHT

Tags: c++, networking, dht

I am trying to use this Distributed Hash Table implementation https://github.com/savoirfairelinux/opendht
but am a complete newbie to networking. So to me even this example on the front page is overwhelming.

```
#include <opendht.h>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
dht::DhtRunner node;

// Launch a dht node on a new thread, using a
// generated RSA key pair, and listen on port 4222.
node.run(4222, dht::crypto::generateIdentity(), true);

// Join the network through any running node,
// here using a known bootstrap node.
node.bootstrap("bootstrap.ring.cx", "4222");

// put some data on the dht
std::vector<uint8_t> some_data(5, 10);
node.put("unique_key", some_data);

// put some data on the dht, signed with our generated private key
node.putSigned("unique_key_42", some_data);

// get data from the dht
node.get("other_unique_key", [](const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<dht::Value>>& values) {
    // Callback called when values are found
    for (const auto& value : values)
        std::cout << "Found value: " << *value << std::endl;
    return true; // return false to stop the search
});

// wait for dht threads to end
node.join();
return 0;
}
```

My questions are for the port numbers? Can those be any port numbers? Is there a range of viable numbers?

The "bootstrap.ring.cx", what's that. Is that some unique adress that anyone can connect to? If so how would I connect to differenct computers instead of connecting to that address.

Overall I just want to connect to computers and get a proof of concept that I can send and retrieve data to two separate machines. Anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 0):

Was working on the same thing right now and saw that this still has no answers so I will add what I got from my short time working with this library for other people facing the same problem.

So for your first question

> My questions are for the port numbers? Can those be any port numbers? Is there a range of viable numbers?

That largely depends what port number you are talking about.

With `node.run(4222, dht::crypto::generateIdentity(), true);` you start a OpenDHT node on your own machine inside of it's own thread (thats what the `true` in the call is for). The port you pass to the `node.run()` function is the port the node should bind to on your local machine, so as long as another socket isn't bound to this port already, it doesn't matter which one you choose. If you pick one that already is used, this line will throw an exception.

With `node.bootstrap("bootstrap.ring.cx", "4222");` on the other hand, you tell your own local node to connect to an existing network over a known remote node running on another machine. So of course here you can't choose any port you like, because you have to pick the one the remote host is "listening" on.

> The "bootstrap.ring.cx", what's that. Is that some unique adress that anyone can connect to? If so how would I connect to differenct computers instead of connecting to that address.

As far as I know `bootstrap.ring.cx` just is a public node of an existing network that just happens to run on the "default" OpenDHT port 4222.

If you want to connect to another existing network you just have to replace the node address and port with the one you'd like in the `node.bootstrap()` call.

> Overall I just want to connect to computers and get a proof of concept that I can send and retrieve data to two separate machines. Anyone have a clue?

So far so good but how do you create your own network and connect to it now?

Well basically you just have to give the program some kind of command line flag to tell it if it should just start up as a bootstrap node, or if you want to connect to an existing network.
If you want to start the note as a bootstrap node, you basically just have to run the `node.run(4222, dht::crypto::generateIdentity(), true);` part and just leave out the `node.bootstrap()` call. From what I've tried it is sufficient if the node is started like that. You should be able to connect to it. But there is another way to call the `node.run()` function where you can pass in the node config and manually change it. With that you can set the node to run as a bootstrap node. I'm not exactly sure what that does but I think is just means that the node is designated as an entry point into the network. If you wanted to run your node as a bootstrap node, you can do it like this:

```
// Launch a dht node on a new thread, using a
// generated RSA key pair, and listen on the given port.
// Set the note as bootstrap node when not connecting to existing network.

dht::DhtRunner::Config cfg = dht::DhtRunner::Config();
cfg.threaded = true;
cfg.client_identity = dht::crypto::generateIdentity();
cfg.dht_config.node_config.is_bootstrap = true;
cfg.dht_config.node_config.network = 0; // I think you can leave out that part as it defaults to 0
node.run(4222, cfg);
```

After that you basically just have to keep the main thread alive trough a `while (true)` loop for example, and you should be able to connect to it from another node.

If the command line flag to connect to an existing network is passed, you somehow need to input the address and port of the of the machine your bootstrap node runs on (or you just hard code it in) and in that case you additionally run `node.bootstrap()` to initiate the connection.

```
if (conn_to_existing_network) {
    // Join the network through the running node.
    node.bootstrap(bootstrap_IP, bootstrap_port);
}
```

Despite that small difference you can now use both nodes to put in and get data from the DHT in the same way.

To put a simple string key value pair in the DHT, you can use

```
node.put(
    dht::InfoHash::get("some_key"),
    dht::Value(
        (const uint8_t*) "some_value",
        strlen("some_value")
    )
);
```

and to retrieve it

```
auto values = node.get(dht::InfoHash::get("some_key")).get();
for (const auto& v : values) {
    auto data = v->data.data();
    cout << "Got value: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < v->size(); i++) {
        cout << data[i];
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

If you want a fully working example, take a look at [this](https://github.com/ElCap1tan/peace/blob/main/main.cpp) small program I've written.